# Google TV not able to enable wifi in emulator

Tags: android, wifi, google-tv

Can any one suggest how to enable wifi in google tv emulator. Not able to pair the android device to google tv emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You can't enable wifi in the emulator.

If you are basing your code on the Google TV Remote project, then you can change this code to ignore the wifi network: http://code.google.com/p/google-tv-remote/source/browse/src/com/google/android/apps/tvremote/DeviceFinder.java

```
private boolean isSimulator() {
      return Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("generic");
  }

  private boolean isWifiAvailable() {
    try {
        if (isSimulator()) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
          return false;
        }
        WifiInfo info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
        return info != null && info.getIpAddress() != 0;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "isWifiAvailable", e);
    }
    return false;
  }
```